# Web services roads traffic and accidents

Tags: web-services, dictionary, traffic

Is anyone know a web service which give information about traffic congestion and accidents? I would like to utilize this information in an iPad app.

I already found the [Yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/traffic/) about traffic but it's not available anymore (I don't know why). I've also found this [website](http://diffusion-numerique.info-routiere.gouv.fr/acces-aux-donnees-de-trafic-a10.html) but the information is not provided via web services (but in XML files) and there is just a few cities.

Comment: It may be worth your following the [stackexchange proposal for finding APIs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36863/api-finder?referrer=VdJYRQ7QN2gB3tYqVdVDjQ2), as this sort of question would be ideal if the site gets to launch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bing Maps APIs** provide traffic coverage for France. Traffic incident text is provided in the primary language of the country where the incident occurs.

**Traffic Flow**: Traffic flow refers lines of color representing different levels of traffic congestion that display on a Bing map.

**Traffic Incidents**: Traffic incidents are reports of traffic issues, such as the report of an accident. Traffic incidents are provided by APIs such as the Bing Maps REST Services Traffic API and the Bing Maps AJAX Control 7.0 Microsoft.Maps.Traffic API.

[Bing Maps Traffic Coverage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj136866.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Mapquest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/traffic-ws) offers a service like that, and as far as I know they are the only company that does it free of charge these days. The market leader for paid traffic information services is [INRIX](http://www.inrix.com/), depending on the size of your project you might also want to take a look into their range of products.

Comment: Mapquest is only for american cities, right ? Because I'm looking for a web service which know french cities.. :/
Thanks !

Comment: Well, Mapquest covers the whole world, but their traffic service seems to be US only, unfortunately...